# How can I back up my Windows Azure table storage?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage

I would like to be able to back up my table storage and also I have a need to move the data (export and import) from my production to development environment on my desktop.

Does anyone know of any tools or method that I can use to this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Cerebrata's Azure Management Cmdlets product. It allows you to download and restore your Azure table storage (and many more things). You can download it from [here.](http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

http://clumsyleaf.com/products/tablexplorer

TableXplorer will let you export all table data to an XML or CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, there are tools out there that let you download your data in various formats, but it's worth noting that none of these are a true backup like you might be used to getting with SQL server.

As far as I'm aware they all just run a regular table storage query to scan through all of the records in the table and save out the results.  If you have a reasonable amount of data (and if you're using table storage then you probably do) it's quite possible that this backup could take an hour or more.

For the sake of simplicity let's say you have two large related tables, A and B.  If the backup starts by backing up table A, then moves on to table B, by the time it finishes backing up table B, it might contain records that rely on data in table A that's just not there.

If you just want to refresh the data in your development environment, this could be perfectly acceptable, but you do need to be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [try this solution](http://docalabs.codeplex.com/) it lets you to backup/restore your tables and blobs to the same or different storage account.